# Data manipulation with Node and mongo when Data size is very large

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async.js, bigdata

I am currently working with MEAN stack. I have around 99000 records in mongo dB. each record consist of an image array, which is containing image urls. maximum size of this image array can be 10. so every record can maximum have imageURL array length = 10 .

Now I want to fetch every records, and then compare images of every records with each other, using resemble js. then save their average value in that same record.

I used async module and tried to implement this, but it is taking too much time even with 5 records. also used async's forEachLimit but it won't help.

So basically How can I manipulate these kind of large amount of data with Node and mongo?

is there any way to do it in batches ? any other solution ?

```
loop1 ==> all records (response) {
    loop2 == > convert all images of one record to base64 (resemble can't use images from urls)==> saved in new array = TempArray1 <==loop ends
    loop3 == > TempArray1.length (TempArray1[i]) {
        loop4 ==> TempArray1.length (TempArray1[j]){
            count += resemble(TempArray1[i],TempArray1[j]);
        }
        avg[i] = count/(TempArray1.length -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on compare part and average value with some example? What is the average value and are you comparing all the urls of one document with another.

Comment: @Sikorski for 1 record,we have an array containing urls. now we have to convert it to base64 image uri and saved in new array. we are using 2 loops to compare images.e.g image 1 will be compared with all images through resemble js function and then we get all comparision value of image 1 to all other.then finding avg value from all of those value, which will be final comparision value fot that particular image.this has to be follow for all Image URIs of one record. this has to be loop over all records.

Comment: @Sikorski if still confusing, let me know. it is hard to paste code in comment due to length